# How can I determine centrality in a node graph in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

First of all this is not homework, just trying to learn Prolog on my own :)

I've been reading about graph theory and I thought it would be cool to implement betweeness centrality in my pet project. I have a list of cities and want to determine which one is more common in all shortest paths possible but I'm not sure how to get all two city combinations.

I already have a rule that gets the shortest path between two cities.

Comment: `findall/3` or another all soultions predicate will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm ... [Betweenness Centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality). Complexity according to [Betweenness Centrality -- Incremental and Faster](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2147) is *O(mn + n^2 log n) time, where n = |V| and m = |E|* for the common algorithm, but can be improved with incremental edge updates. Interesting.

But your question is not about Betweenness Centrality but about the Cartesian Product?

To get the cartesian product of cities, you have to create a goal that chains two `member/2` calls, and then collect all solutions thereof with `bagof/3`:

```
cities_1([berlin,tokyo,kigali,moscow]).
cities_2([beijing,new_delhi,cairo,lisboa]).

cartesian_product(CityPairs) :-
   cities_1(L1), 
   cities_2(L2), 
   bagof([C1,C2],(member(C1,L1),member(C2,L2)),CityPairs).
```

Comment: Hmmm I think I understand what you did there but I have only one big list of cities and the Cartesian Product is only useful when you have two graphs right?

Comment: @JoãoVaz Well, the two lists can be the same. You wanted all pairs of cities, right?

Comment: Yes! I thought I could work it out having all the pairs but since betweeness centrality of X is determined by the sum of every shortest path thats passes through X divided by the total of shortest paths, I'm still having trouble getting an algorithm for that